# Doesn't work this Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a code which I'm find on internet, I would use it but do not know where is the mistake. This is Calendary with the Cookie saving, Just that someone hovers why it does not work

```
window.onload = function () {
    zegar();
    WHCheckCookies();
};
function zegar()
{
    var nazwy_mies = ['Styczeń', ' Luty', 'Marzec', 'Kwiecień', 'Maj', 'Czerwiec', 'Lipiec', 'Sierpień', 'Wrzesień', 'Październik', 'Listopad', 'Grudzień'];
    var nazwy_dni = ['Niedziela', 'Poniedziałek', 'Wtorek', 'Środa', 'Czwartek', 'Piątek', 'Sobota'];
    var data = new Date();
    var rok = data.getFullYear();
    var mies = data.getMonth();
    var dzien = data.getDay();
    var dzienl = data.getDate();
    var godz = data.getHours();
    var min = data.getMinutes();
    var sec = data.getSeconds();
    if (min < 10)
        min = '0' + min;
    if (sec < 10)
        sec = '0' + sec;
    var dic = nazwy_dni[dzien] + ' ' + dzienl + ' ' + nazwy_mies[mies] + ' ' + rok + ', ' + godz + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
    document.getElementById('czas').innerHTML = dic;
    setTimeout("zegar();", 1000);
}
function WHCreateCookie(name, value, days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
function WHReadCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function WHCheckCookies() {
    if (WHReadCookie('cookies_accepted') != 'T') {
        var message_container = document.createElement('div');
        message_container.id = 'cookies-message-container';
        var html_code = '<div id="cookies-message" style="font-size: 17px; color:#00FF00; border: 1px solid #ff0000; text-align: center; position: fixed; top: 0px; background-color: #000000;">Ta strona używa ciasteczek dzięki którym nasz serwis może działać lepiej <br>Co to ciasteczka?<br>To niewielkie pliki tekstowe, nazywane ciasteczkami (z ang. cookie – ciastko), wysyłane przez serwis internetowy, który odwiedzamy i zapisywane na urządzeniu końcowym (komputerze, laptopie, smartfonie), z którego korzystamy podczas przeglądania stron internetowych.<br>Aby dowiedzieć się więcej na ten temat <a href="http://wszystkoociasteczkach.pl" target="_blank">Kliknij tutaj</a><br>Jeżeli rozumiesz i zgadzasz się na wysyłanie ciasteczek <a href="java script:WHCloseCookiesWindow();" id="accept-cookies-checkbox" name="accept-cookies" style="background-color: #ff0000; padding: 5px 10px; color: #000000; border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;">Kliknij tutaj</a></div>';
        message_container.innerHTML = html_code;
        document.body.appendChild(message_container);
    }
}
function WHCloseCookiesWindow() {
    WHCreateCookie('cookies_accepted', 'T', 365);
    document.getElementById('cookies-message-container').removeChild(document.getElementById('cookies-message'));
}
```

Why?

Comment: This is html to this
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
window.onload = function(){
    zegar();
    WHCheckCookies();
};
```

to

```
zegar();
WHCheckCookies();
```

You don't need to use `window.onload` event when your script isn't a "HTML" inline.